# Single Sign On in Angular Applications without Third Party Tools

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on

We have 2 Angular applications. The first one (let's call it PO) has been created in Angular 1 and is running live, while the other (we may call it XPP) is to be created in Angular 5. Both of them use/will use ASP.net Web API for server-side interactions.

The user registration can be done only through PO. Also, only PO has access to the database containing all registered users. PO uses OWIN, but not Identity.

Now, the 2 applications must share log-on, i.e., if the user has logged into either one, they are considered logged into the other one as well. We have looked at many articles for this, but none seems to exactly fit into this situation. Also, we are not allowed to use third-party solutions like auth0.

How do we implement single sign on (SSO) between the 2 applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can use token system to continue the session.

For Eg. Firstly, user logged in through first application. then application will receive token and that token will be used by the backend to authenticate the user.

if you will change the site from first to second then just pass the token via URL (query string). and again use same token for authentication.

like this, you can easily use same session for both application.